# While passing data from parent to child, it passes but view doesn't get updated

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a a root and a child component. I am trying to pass data using the props from parent to child.

```
<div id="root">
    <my-component v-bind:account-types='accountTypes'>
    </my-component>
</div>

Vue.component('my-component', {
   props: ['accountTypes'],
   data() {
    return { accounts: Object.assign({},this.accountTypes) }
   },
    template: `
       <div v-for="x in accounts"></div> // I kept it short for this line. It returns 0
    `
}
```

Through Vue debugger extension, I can see my-component has the accountTypes but id doesn't show.

The object structure is like this:

```
 var obj = {
      1 : [ "a", "z", "k", "m" ]
      2 : [ "a", "b", "c", "d" ]
 }
```

And in my main app,

```
var app = new Vue({

el: '#root',

data: {
    accountTypes : {},
}, 



methods : {
    // selecting & pushing
    accountTypeSelected(clientIndex, formName, action) {
        if (action == 'add') {
            this.pushValue(clientIndex, formName)
        } else {
            this.removeFromArray(clientIndex, formName)
        }
    },

 // And these are what I use for push and delete:
    pushValue(key, value) {
        var obj = this.accountTypes

        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            var idx = $.inArray(value, obj[key]);
            if (idx == -1) {
                obj[key].push(value);
            }
        } else {
            obj[key] = [value];
        }
    },

    removeFromArray(key, val) {
        var idx = $.inArray(val, this.accountTypes[key]);
        if (idx != -1) {
            this.accountTypes[key].splice(idx, 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 1 : { "a", "z", "k", "m" }??? not an array  ??  1 : ["a", "z", "k", "m" ], there is no key/value pair so is an array

Comment: you have issue in `v-bind` .

It should be `<my-component
        v-bind:accountTypes='accountTypes'>
    </my-component>`
Refer : 
https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#v-bind-Shorthand

Comment: Ah sorry. They are array. Also, sorry about the type on `v-bind:`. Fixing them now but these are not the case. Thanks for pointing out

Comment: Still not fixed. Your `v-bind` is outside the `my-component` tag.

Answer (score 0):

You are initializing `accounts` from `accountTypes`, but initialization is a one-time thing. Updates to `accountTypes` will not re-initialize `accounts`.

If you want the child to stay up-to-date with the parent, then you should get rid of `accounts` and just use `accountTypes`.

Comment: I tried that too. I tried just setting it `props: ['accountTypes'],` in my component and `<my-component v-bind:account-types='accountTypes'>` in the element. In the debugger, I can see the account types value gets updated in my component successfully, in fact the for loop doesn't seem to work. `<second-comp v-for="(account, index) in accountTypes[0]" :key="index"></second-comp>`

Comment: `accountTypes` is not an array. Is there any way you could make a snippet or a fiddle that shows the problem and what you expect it to do that it is not doing?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/50wL7mdz/51201/ - Here, I prepared a fiddle. It works if you use a digit in for loop but not my object :( The expected behaviour is that it returns each array value as well as their keys. So one for all a,b,c, e,b,g  for fiddle's example, and I want to be able to know their keys as well. Just like `(val, key, index in accountTypes)`

Comment: You had an invalid comment (HTML style comment in JavaScript code), and you needed to kebab-case `account-types` as a v-bind attribute. https://jsfiddle.net/50wL7mdz/51207/

Comment: Using the $set is the answer